# GWT Getting Google User's Name After Successful OAuth Login

Tags: gwt, oauth

In my GWT application, I am using the `com.google.api.gwt.oauth2.OAuth2` module to allow users to signin with OAuth.  I have implemented a GoogleApi class to provide the OAuth login as follows:

```java
public final class GoogleApi {
    private EventBus eventBus;

    private final ClientOAuth2Login oAuth2Login;
    private ClientGoogleApiRequestTransport requestTransport;

    private String accessToken;

    public GoogleApi(final EventBus eventBus, String clientId) {
        this.eventBus = eventBus;
        oAuth2Login = new ClientOAuth2Login(clientId);
    }

    ...

    public void login(final Receiver<String> callback) {
        oAuth2Login.login(new Receiver<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(String response) {
                accessToken = response;
                callback.onSuccess(response);
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(ServerFailure error) {
                Window.alert(error.getMessage());
            }
        });
    }
    ...
}
```

I am calling this login() method as follows:

```java
googleApi.login(new Receiver<String>() {
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(final String token) {
        // I want to get the logged in user's name here
    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(ServerFailure error) {
        ...
    }
});
```

After successful login, I want to get the logged in user's full name.  I know that I can get the user's name using the `com.google.api.gwt.services.Plus` module, but that requires users to be registered to Google Plus and throws an error if they're not.

**How can I do this using OAuth in my GWT app?**  Basically, I want to be able to implement [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7115414) in a GWT app, if possible.

Comment: Have a look at https://code.google.com/p/gwt-google-apis/source/browse/trunk/apis/samples/plus/com/google/api/gwt/samples/plus/client/PlusEntryPoint.java or https://code.google.com/p/gwt-oauth2/source/browse/trunk/samples/multi/com/google/api/gwt/oauth2/samples/multi/client/OAuth2SampleEntryPoint.java depending on which library you use.

Comment: Thank you for your response, Thomas.  The code at your first link uses Google Plus to get the user's name & other info.  The second does not have the code to retrieve the user's name.

Answer (score 1):

Have you see this? I thought it was quite useful. It is, however, a lot of code to achieve a simple result:

http://www.sw-engineering-candies.com/blog-1/howtogetuserinformationwithoauth2inagwtandgoogleappenginejavaapplication

Comment: Thanks, Dirk. Your code uses AppEngine-specific API.  It wont work on other hosts.